# Determine the start time of a dialled call with <Dial>

Tags: twilio

I am creating a call back system. This system will first call the A party, using REST API. Once the A party answers the call and press 1, the B party is called using the  verb.

I would like to know the time when the B party answered the call. Dial has an action URL, but that URL will be called only when the call ends. A way to accomplish that is to use the DialCallDuration attribute, when the call has ended. However, I need to know the time, while the call is in progress.

What is the best way to find the time when B party answered the call?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

I believe you can use the [`<Number>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number) noun for this.  Number has an attribute named [`url`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number#attributes-url) which Twilio will request when Party B answers, but before they are connected to Party A.

```
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Number url="[YOUR_APP]">+15555555555</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

The request to 'url' should have the start_time parameter.

Hope that helps.